# Apache httpd poll() takes 38 ms

Tags: apache, encryption, polling, latency

I have an Apache (OHS) httpd process (1 out of 8 actually) talking to 2 web entry servers (WES), both on RedHat. Plotting the response times taken from the respective logfiles shows a constant delta of around 50 ms between both. Using strace `strace -o <trace output> -ttT -s 2048 -f -xx -p <Pid>` I found that in 85% of the requests (where encrypted transfer is involved) the httpd process is somehow stuck in `poll()`, which returns only after 38.something ms. The remaining 10 ms are mainly due to excessive `gettimeofday()` and other `time()` related system calls. The WES on the other hand claims he could send the data within below 100 µs but accuses "resource temporarily unavailable" via `recvfrom()` and now `poll()`s on his side for some 50 ms before `recvfrom()` finishes (with the confirmation of the data transfer from the Apache, I suppose).

**WES:**

```
40685 16:54:57.111496 poll([{fd=39, events=POLLOUT|POLLWRNORM}], 1, 300000) = 1 ([{fd=39, revents=POLLOUT|POLLWRNORM}]) <0.000071>  
40685 16:54:57.111666 sendto(39,  "     <encrypted data>  )    ", 1053, 0, NULL, 0) = 1053 <0.000067>  
40685 16:54:57.112249 recvfrom(39, 0x7ff8380c0243, 5, 0, 0, 0) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable) <0.000061>  
40685 16:54:57.112405 poll([{fd=39, events=POLLIN}], 1, 300000 <unfinished ...>  
40685 16:54:57.165084 <... poll resumed> ) = 1 ([{fd=39, revents=POLLIN}]) <0.052659>  
40685 16:54:57.165177 recvfrom(39,  "   ", 1, MSG_PEEK, NULL, NULL) = 1 <0.000114>  
40685 16:54:57.165388 ioctl(39, FIONREAD, [205]) = 0 <0.000078>
```

**Apache (OHS):**

```
63195 16:54:57.145220 <... poll resumed> ) = 1 ([{fd=22, revents=POLLIN}]) <0.038408>  
63195 16:54:57.145299 read(22,  "      <encrypted data>  ", 8000) = 1053 <0.000018>  
63195 16:54:57.145739 clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, {1435589697, 145769536}) = 0 <0.000018>  
63195 16:54:57.145810 gettimeofday({1435589697, 145826}, NULL) = 0 <0.000025>
63195 16:54:57.145879 clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, {1435589697, 145902010}) = 0 <0.000021>  
63195 16:54:57.145960 clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, {1435589697, 145986422}) = 0 <0.000017>
```

I have two questions:

1. Is the information in the trace output sufficient to identify the cause of the excessive `poll()` 38 ms (and obviously what is it then)?
2. What can be done to improve tracing in case 1) must be answered with no?

Comment: You really need to format your code properly.  Take a read through here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting